# Algorithm for reversing certain characters in long strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, reverse

I'm currently working on a programming question:

> Given a string *s* and an integer *k*, reverse the first *k* characters for every 2*k* characters counting from the start of the string.
>
> If there are fewer than *k* characters left, reverse all of them. If there are less than 2*k* but greater than or equal to *k* characters, then reverse the first *k* characters and leave the other as original.

I created a program that solves the first 45 of the 60 test cases, but apparently falls apart on really long strings. When fed strings of 999 characters, the last few came out as nonsense.

I cannot see any fault in my code that may have caused that. Any feedback? Simple solutions or just better ways of constructing my code?

```js
function reverseArrayOfChars(sArray) {
  const length = sArray.length;
  let temp;
  for (let s = 0; s < length / 2; s++) {
    temp = sArray[s];
    sArray[s] = sArray[length - 1 - s];
    sArray[length - 1 - s] = temp;
  }
  return sArray;
}

function reverseStr(s, k) {
  let sArray = s.split("");
  let newArray = []; //Final array to be returned
  let tempArray = []; //tempArray is used to store returns from reverseArrayOfChars function. These returns are then concatenated onto newArray.
  let switchBoard = 1; //Used to 'switch' between two conditions. Changes automatically every iteration of the loop.
  for (let counter = 0; counter < sArray.length; counter += k) {
    switchBoard = switchBoard === 0 ? 1 : 0;
    if (sArray.length - counter < k) {
      tempArray = reverseArrayOfChars(sArray.slice(counter));
      newArray = newArray.concat(tempArray);
      break;
    } else if (sArray.length - counter > k && sArray.length < k * 2) {
      tempArray = reverseArrayOfChars(sArray.slice(counter, counter + k));
      newArray = newArray.concat(tempArray);
      tempArray = sArray.slice(counter + k);
      newArray = newArray.concat(tempArray);
      break;
    } else if (switchBoard === 0) {
      tempArray = reverseArrayOfChars(sArray.slice(counter, counter + k));
      newArray = newArray.concat(tempArray);
    } else if (switchBoard === 1) {
      tempArray = sArray.slice(counter, counter + k);
      newArray = newArray.concat(tempArray);
    }
  }
  return newArray.join("");
```

Comment: https://dev.to/cod3pineapple/leetcode-541-reverse-string-ii-javascript-solution-4o9o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, you could try this sample code:

```
var reverseStr = function(s, k) {
    if (k > s.length) 
        return s.split('').reverse().join('');
    
    const split = s.split('');
    
    // reverse the seg. then join it back
    for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i += 2*k) {
        const reverse = split.splice(i, k).reverse();
        split.splice(i, 0, ...reverse);
    }
    
    return split.join('');
};
```